# issue encountered regarding changing value in dataset

Tags: r

I am making sales prediction for different brands in the supermarket and I want to replace in particular the regular prices of DOVE deodorant that has lower price level than the sales price with the sale price. I have tried the following command in R:

```
newthesis$DOVERPrice[newthesis$DOVERPrice < newthesis$DOVEPrice] <- newthesis$DOVEPrice
```

With this command the compiler gives the following message:

```
Warning message:
In newthesis$AXERPrice[newthesis$AXERPrice < newthesis$AXEPrice] <- newthesis$AXEPrice :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I want to ask what this message indicates and wether this would be the appropriate way to change value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `...  <- newthesis$DOVEPrice[newthesis$DOVERPrice < newthesis$DOVEPrice]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be wanting a vector that is the pairwise maximum of two vectors.

```
set.seed(1)

dtf <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20), 10))

dtf$max <- apply(dtf[,1:2], 1, max)

# or
dtf$max <- pmax(dtf[,1], dtf[,2])

head(dtf)
#    V1 V2 max
# 1   6  3   6
# 2   8  2   8
# 3  11 20  20
# 4  16 10  16
```

You get the error because the vector you want to replace is not the same length as the one you want to replace it with.

```
dtf$V1[dtf$V1 < dtf$V2]

# is shorter than

dtf$V2

# this will work, because the two vectors are of the same length
dtf$V1[dtf$V1 < dtf$V2] <- dtf$V2[dtf$V1 < dtf$V2]
```

The error talks about `multiple of replacement length` because strictly speaking they don't have to be of the same length. The one you replace with can be shorter, as long as its length is a divisor of the length of the vector you are replacing.

```
# that's why this works
dtf$V1[dtf$V1 < dtf$V2] <- NA

# and this
dtf$V1[dtf$V1 < dtf$V2] <- 1:2

# but not this
dtf$V1[dtf$V1 < dtf$V2] <- 1:3
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, with that I solved the problem :)